# shut down ("destroy") libvirt VM when it reboots

Tags: linux, ubuntu, kvm, libvirt

For a while, I was using `virt-install` to install an OS on libvirt VMs. I learned that the OS has an autoinstaller feature that requires the use of a second CD-ROM (to feed information about the desired configuration to the installer), but I found that `virt-install` unfortunately ignores all but one `--cdrom` argument. The alternative that I came up with is to output the VM configuration `virt-install` *would* use with just one CD-ROM to a file using the `--print-xml` argument, edit that file to add the second CD-ROM, and then use `virsh create <xml config file>`.

When I was using `virt-install` before, the VM rebooted itself at the end of installation and `virt-install` would notice and shut down ("destroy") the VM instead of allowing it to reboot, leaving me with a nice clean installed disk image. However, now when the VM reboots after completing installation, it actually boots up again instead of shutting down cleanly, so I can't programmatically tell when the installation has completed. After the reboot it looks like the same `qemu-system-x86_64` process is being used, so I also can't use it to tell when the installation has completed.

How can I force libvirt to shut down ("destroy") the VM instead of rebooting the way `virt-install` did? Alternatively, is there some other indicator I can use to tell that a VM reboot has occurred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there doesn't seem to be a way to automatically destroy a libvirt VM on reboot through a special incantation of `virsh create` or by changing options in the domain XML file, I stumbled across the very useful `virsh event` command:

```
$ virsh help event
  NAME
    event - (null)

  SYNOPSIS
    event [<domain>] [<event>] [--all] [--loop] [--timeout <number>] [--list]

  DESCRIPTION
    List event types, or wait for domain events to occur

  OPTIONS
    [--domain] <string>  filter by domain name, id, or uuid
    [--event] <string>   which event type to wait for
    --all                wait for all events instead of just one type
    --loop               loop until timeout or interrupt, rather than one-shot
    --timeout <number>   timeout seconds
    --list               list valid event types
```

The command blocks until an event of the specified type occurs for the specified domain. This allowed me to achieve my goal of emulating the behavior in `virt-install` by doing:

```
$ virsh event domain1 --event restart
event 'reboot' for domain -
events received: 1
$ virsh destroy domain1
```

And it even gives me a built-in timeout mechanism!